# Jquery: Reset (enable) Select options that were previously disabled onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a "sector" field that disables/enables select options depending on what the end user choose from the "name" field.

This happens using an onchange function. The onChange aspect works fine, but I am having troubles "reseting" the "sector" field if a user chooses a selection for a second time from the "name" field.

```
$('#filter_pname').change(function() { 
    $('#filter_secteur option').attr("enabled", "true"); // reset attempt

    var variable = $('#filter_pname option:selected').data('secteur');
    $('#filter_secteur option:not(:contains('+ variable +'))').attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

If a second selection is chosen, the disabled fields remain disabled.

https://jsfiddle.net/invisionweb/kysfzbdy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing `.attr("enabled", "true");`, do this instead: `.removeAttr('disabled');` or `.attr("disabled", false);`

```
$('#filter_pname').change(function() { 
    $('#filter_secteur option').removeAttr('disabled'); // reset attempt

    var variable = $('#filter_pname option:selected').data('secteur');
    $('#filter_secteur option:not(:contains('+ variable +'))').attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```